# Fortiweb masked subdomain filter

Tags: fortigate, forticlient

Is there any way to redirect masked subdomains to correct server in **Fortiweb**?
For example, i know that subdomain will be masked like `server_name "~^(?<subdomain>[A-Za-z][0-9]{2}([A-Za-z][0-9]){2})\.domain\.com$` and i want to redirect it to correct server.
Now we just block this kind of subdomains in WAF.